# kafka listener for meteor

Tags: meteor, apache-kafka

I want to consume Kafka messages in Meteor.

Is there any package in meteor to do it? how should approach this? I searched and I could find npm for node.js which can listen to kafka messages but not sure how this can be used in meteor.

Thank you

Comment: Did  you make any progress with this?

Comment: I'd advise you to ask a new question for that then

Comment: Hi, I was able to use meteorhacks:npm - and use kafka-node npm module and consume Kafka message in Meteor. Thank for your help.

Comment: If you found my answer useful, please mark it as such, so future viewers of this question know it is the correct suggestion

Comment: Hi I am not sure how to mark it, can you let me know. I tried to give a up vote for your answer but it says I need 15 reputations.

Comment: I think you can mark it as correct by clicking the tick icon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [meteorhacks:npm](https://atmospherejs.com/meteorhacks/npm) package, which will allow you to use npm packages in your meteor app. Here is a [blog post](https://meteorhacks.com/complete-npm-integration-for-meteor) explaining how to use it (though the package README should be sufficient)

Comment: see: https://github.com/SOHU-Co/kafka-node for specific client in node; but also you need to do the wrapper for the package to be used in meteor.

Comment: @andhdo Can you show me how to wrap `kafka-node` for use in Meteor. I found problem `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './lib/BufferMaker'` when use it directly. And Browserify is supported by default in 1.5.1. https://guide.meteor.com/using-npm-packages.html#client-npm

Answer (score 0):

[`kafka-node`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kafka-node) would be the package that you might want to try.  It is important to note that this is a server-side only package.  Therefore you need to make sure to only import it from modules under `/server`.  You can, of course, trigger sending messages from the client as well, but for that, you will need to wrap the kafka functionality in purely server-side meteor methods.  Shared code will not work.

If you see an error message in your browser console such as `Error: Cannot find module './lib/BufferMaker'` then it is because the kafka-node package is also imported on the client.